# Why does row level locking not appear to work correctly in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking

This is a continuation from [When I update/insert a single row should it lock the entire table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248011)

Here is my problem.

I have a table that holds locks so that other records in the system don’t have to take locks out on common resources, but can still queue the tasks so that they get executed one at a time.

When I access a record in this locks table I want to be able to lock it and update it (just the one record) without any other process being able to do the same.  I am able to do this with a lock hint such as **updlock**.

What happens though is that even though I’m using a rowlock to lock the record, it blocks a request to another process to alter a completely unrelated row in the same table that would also have specified the **updlock** hint along with **rowlock**.

You can recreate this be making a table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locks](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LockName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Locked] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Locks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locks] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Locks_LockName]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [LockName]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Locks] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Locks_Locked]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Locked]
GO
```

Add two rows for a lock with **LockName=‘A’** and one for **LockName=‘B’**

Then create two queries to run in a transaction at the same time against it:

**Query 1:**

```
Commit
Begin transaction
select * From Locks with (updlock rowlock) where LockName='A'
```

**Query 2:**

```
select * From Locks with (updlock rowlock) where LockName='B'
```

Please note that I am leaving the transaction open so that you can see this issue since it wouldn’t be visible without this open transaction.

When you run **Query 1** locks are issues for the row and any subsequent queries for **LockName=’A’** will have to wait.  This behaviour is correct.

Where this gets a bit frustrating is when you run **Query 2** you are blocked until **Query 1** finishes even thought these are unrelated records.  If you then run **Query 1** again just as I have it above, it will commit the previous transaction, **Query 2** will run and then **Query 1** will once again lock the record.

Please offer some suggestions as to how I might be able to have it properly lock **ONLY** the one row and not prevent other items from being updated as well.

PS. Holdlock also fails to produce the correct behaviour after one of the rows is updated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, the lock hints are applied to the objects scanned, not matched.

Normally, the engine places a shared lock on the objects (pages etc) while reading them and lifts them (or does not lift in `SERIALIZABLE` transactions) after the scanning is done.

However, you instruct the engine to place (and lift) the update locks which are not compatible with each other.

The transaction `B` locks while trying to put an `UPDLOCK` onto the row already locked with an `UPDLOCK` by transaction `A`.

If you create an index and force its usage (so no conflicting reads ever occur), your tables will not lock:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_locks_lockname ON locks (lockname)

Begin transaction
select * From Locks with (updlock rowlock INDEX (ix_locks_lockname)) where LockName='A'

Begin transaction
select * From Locks with (updlock rowlock INDEX (ix_locks_lockname)) where LockName='B'
```

Comment: That was a great answer and thanks for posting useful code for it.  Is there a way to get sql to default ot this mode?

Comment: @Middletone: what is "default"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should really be asking how to get SQL to use an index instead of a table scan because that sounds a bit like what's caused it not to use the index on the table.  Is there a way to have it always lock on the primary key regardless of how it finds the record in the table?  That's my view of default.

Comment: @Middletone: I'm afraid you can't (reliably). You can try some unholy magic involving the self joins on the tables with different locking options and forcing the access path to nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

For query 2, try using the [READPAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint - this (quote):

> Specifies that the Database Engine not
>   read rows that are locked by other
>   transactions. Under most
>   circumstances, the same is true for
>   pages. When READPAST is specified,
>   both row-level and page-level locks
>   are skipped. That is, the Database
>   Engine skips past the rows or pages
>   instead of blocking the current
>   transaction until the locks are
>   released

This is typically used in queue-processing type environments - so multiple processes can pull off the next item from a queue table without being blocked out by other processes (of course, using UPDLOCK to prevent multiple processes picking up the same row).

**Edit 1:**
It could be caused if you don't have an index on the LockName field. With the index, query 2 could do an index seek to the exact row. But without it, it would be doing a scan (checking every row) meaning it gets held up by the first transaction. So if it's not indexed, try indexing it.

Comment: If I use readpast and another process has locked **b** then nothing would be returned and that would be just as much of a problem.  This also does not solve the original problem of row level locking not working correctly.

Comment: Again changing the index does nothing.  I've gone to the trouble of posted all the code so please test your solution before posting an answer.

Comment: @Middletone - fair enough. A lot of time, it's actually difficult to replicate straight away the specific issue someone is encountering - unless that can be done, it's not always possible to say "this **is** the solution to your problem". I have working solutions, which is what I've based my answers on in trying to help you - plus my time and effort.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot though.  I still appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but typically those who are dealing with similar problems want to use sp_getapplock. Covered by Tony Rogerson:[Assisting Concurrency by creating your own Locks (Mutexs in SQL)](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/06.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want queueing in SQL Server, use [UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition) hints. It works.

I'd consider changing your approach rather than trying to change SQL Server behaviour...