# Exclusive lock on table for Update

Tags: sql-server, database, deadlock, database-deadlocks

It's more theoretical question but I need to do something with it.

I have web interface and SQL Server 2012 behind it. Which is given me a lot of problem on `UPDATE`

I have one table let's call it `Contract` which has 100+ columns.

When user from web interface is doing an `UPDATE` it's exclusively locking whole table instead of only updated row, so the other users can't do `inserts` or `updates` some times `selects` which sometimes is causing multiple deadlocks.

Usually update looks like

```
UPDATE Contract
set 
param1=@1,
param2=@2,
param3=@3,
param4=@4,
.....
where id=@id
```

How to fix this lock or maybe how to tell to SQL Server lock only row on `updates`?

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`?

Comment: SQL Server only locks **individual rows** when doing an `UPDATE` - unless you do an `UPDATE` over more than 5000 rows in a single transaction - in that case, a **lock escalation** would lock the entire table. Does your table have a **primary key**, and if so: which column is it? Is that primary key also the clustered index?

Comment: @wewesthemenace< yes I have clustered and non -clustered indexes.

Comment: This other SO question (and most definitely the expert answers!) might also be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248011/when-i-update-insert-a-single-row-should-it-lock-the-entire-table

Comment: I was going to refer you to the same question. :)

Comment: @marc_s, I thought  the same thing in has to Update only individual rows, but its locking whole table i was checking  but  running  test and always had  exclusive lock on table not on the row. or i am running my test  wrong way

Comment: @Andrey: can you show us a query output that **shows** the full table locking? Are those really `X` locks? Or just `IX` (intent exclusive)?

Comment: What is the value for allow_row_locks in sys.indexes for the table in question?